# Cannot receive calls but can make calls on my tablet HCL ME Y2

Tags: calls, phone-app, gsm

I recently bought a [HCL ME Y2 tablet](http://www.hclstore.in/Products/HCL-Handheld-Devices-ME-Tablets/HCL/HCL-ME-TABLET-Y2/pid-505636.aspx) with Android 4.0.3 (Ice Cream Sandwich) installed.

It has a SIM slot and when I use the Phone dialer (the blue phone icon app), I can make calls over GSM but when someone tries to call this number, the phone vibrates for less than a second while I hear a single ring at the calling phone and immediately after I get the message that the phone is busy.

I cant even sent SMS / receive SMS on the tablet.

I Couldn't find any solution to this, any input?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resetting the device fixed the issue. Give that a try.